# How to iterate over more than 100 items in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am using express and mongodb npm module to insert data into a collection with more than 1300 collection items. I am extracting data from a json file that also has over 1300 objects. With the following code, everything is get correctly inserted until I reach 100 items in the mongodb collection. Is there a way around this without breaking things up into multiple collections?

I'm using the following code in node:

```
 MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db)  {
  db.collection('players').find().forEach(function(myDoc) {
    for(var i = 0; i < jsonfile.length; i++)  {
      if (myDoc.player_ID ==  jsonfile[i].playerID && myDoc.stint_ID == 1)  {
        db.collection('players').updateOne(
          { 'player_ID' : jsonfile[i].playerID},
          { $set: {
            'strikeOut' : jsonfile[i].SO }
          }, function(err, result)  {
            console.log(err);
            db.close();
          }
        );
      } else {
        return;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Best to use the **[`bulkWrite`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#bulkWrite)** API here which greatly improves performance since write operations are sent to the server only once in bulk. Efficiency is achieved since the method does not send every write request to the server (as with the current update statement within the **`forEach()`** loop) but just once in every 1000 requests, thus making updates more efficient and quicker than currently is:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    bulkUpdateOps = [];

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    // Get the collection
    var col = db.collection('players');
    col.find().forEach(function(myDoc) { 
        for(var i = 0; i < jsonfile.length; i++)  {
            if (myDoc.player_ID ==  jsonfile[i].playerID && myDoc.stint_ID == 1)  {
                bulkUpdateOps.push({ 
                    "updateOne": {
                        "filter": { "player_ID": jsonfile[i].playerID },
                        "update": { "$set": { "strikeOut" : jsonfile[i].SO  } }
                     }
                });    
                if (bulkUpdateOps.length === 1000) {
                    col.bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOps).then(function(r) {
                        // do something with the result
                        console.log(r);
                    });
                    bulkUpdateOps = [];
                }
            }
        }
    });         

    if (bulkUpdateOps.length > 0) {
        col.bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOps).then(function(r) { 
            console.log(r); 
            db.close();
        });
    }   
}
```